# mysql calculation several column

Tags: mysql, database

i have a current db with following queries:

Table Name : `service` 
Fields:  `service_id,name,labor_hour,part_cost,rate_id`

```
`service_id` as `primary key`


rate_id as foreign key references rate(rate_id)
```

rate(rate_id,labor_cost_per_hour)
    primary key(rate_id)

Table Name:  `order_service`
Fields :

```
order_service_id,order_id,service_id
    order_service_id as primary key
    order_id as foreign key references order(order_id)
    service_id as foreign key references service(service_id)

service cost = labor hours * labor cost per hour + part cost
```

I want to list the `service id` and `cost of services` whose `costs` are more than certain number. 
I am not sure how to do the calculation for the service cost in mysql; I thought about inner join two tables, but it seems not work. Anyone would give me some helps? Thanks!

Comment: show your query. and more than which certain number

Comment: i am thinking about using sum function...but i am not sure how to do exactly

Comment: did you check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
select service_id,(labor hours * labor cost per hour + part cost) from 
service s INNER JION  
rate r ON r.rate=s.rate 
where  (labor hours * labor cost per hour + part cost) > 500
```

Comment: Is there anyway that i can rename that calculation? like service_cost?

Comment: yes. like `(labor hours * labor cost per hour + part cost) as servicecost`